# React Native ,Flatlist : how to remove 'unread' note ,once you cliked

Tags: react-native

I am making a function ,which is at the begining ,all the message are 'unread' .. And once you click the message ,the unread will disappear .like the example as follow:
[image]

I had made a component **Card.js** :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity,  View } from 'react-native'

function Card({
    img,
    userType,
    visible,
    onPress,
}) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
      
            <Image style={styles.img} source={img}/>
            {/** userType: 0:teacher  1:student 2.other */}
            {userType===0&&(
                <Text style={styles.txt}>teacher</Text>
            )}
             {userType===1&&(
                <Text style={styles.txt}>student</Text>
            )}
             {userType===2&&(
                <Text style={styles.txt}>other</Text>
            )}

            {visible===1&&(
                 <Text style={styles.txt_notice}>Unread</Text>
            )}
            
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        width : '90%',
        flexDirection : 'row',
        justifyContent :'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        marginTop : 10,

    },
    txt : {
        fontSize : 18,
        marginLeft : 20,
    },
    img : {
        width :100,
        height : 100,
        borderRadius : 50,
    },
    txt_notice :{
        fontSize : 16,
        color :'#DC143C',
        marginLeft :10,
    }
})
export default Card;
```

and the screen i used **TryScreen.js**:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/Card';

const clients = [
    {id:1,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/64/02/cb/6402cbd3d436caecad2f3e300d67ebd1.jpg'},userType:0,visible:1},
    {id:2,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/34/d6/8c/34d68c7694e1c43204c0dbc623ce4cb8.jpg'},userType:1,visible:1},
    {id:3,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a0/14/26/a014261951fae6dcc16b4d555f0ef089.jpg'},userType:2,visible:1},
    {id:4,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/96/bf/b6/96bfb641920f527e4fcc9ca23501e222.jpg'},userType:2,visible:1},
    {id:5,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/8b/6e/d9/8b6ed9f0cd6de175537879233a017b0c.jpg'},userType:1,visible:1},
    {id:6,img:{uri:'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0e/16/7f/0e167fab5f152a630fd80dfa1ad3e47c.jpg'},userType:0,visible:1},
]
function TyeScreen(props) {
  
   
    const[clients_list,setClients]=useState([]);
     useEffect(()=>{
        setClients(clients);
     },[]);
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
            data = {clients}
            keyExtractor = {item =>item.id.toString()}
            renderItem = {({item,index})=>(<Card
            img = {item.img}
            userType = {item.userType}
            visible = {item.visible}
            onPress = {()=>{
                item.visible -=1;
                setClients(item);
            }}
            />)}
            />
            
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,
        backgroundColor : '#ffffff',
    }
})

export default TyeScreen;
```

My idea is when click the message ,the 'unread' notice will disappear ... I have tried many ways ,but not worked ... Could you please help me take a look my code ,thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clients-list need to be in the state, something like

```
const [clients, setClients] = useState();
```

then you initialize them in

```
useEffect(() => {
    setClients(...)
})
```

and then in onPress you change the property of the selected client and change the state again.

## Edit

a simple implementation to force re-rendering

```
onPress = (client) => {
  client.unread = -1;
  const newclients = {...clients};
  setClients(newclients);
}
```

Comment: Hey Christian ,thank you so much for your answer .I have tried what you've said . I added :const[clients_list,setClients]=useState([]);
     useEffect(()=>{
        setClients(clients);  
     },[]);    and modified the onPress: onPress= {()=>item.visible-1};but still not work..Could you please help me to take a look if i have a mistake ,thank you so much again ！！

Comment: the basic of react native is state management, you need to update your state when you want to have a re-rendering, I have added an example

Comment: Hey Christian ,I have tried your suggetion ,it  appeared a new problem .. which is when I click one of the item ,all the list disappear... I have reedit the code with your suggestion above ,could you please take a look ?  Thank you sooo much for your patience!!

Comment: Hi Christan ,thank you soooo much for your tips! ,I have finally noticed where were the problem ,I had modified with your suggestion ,and it worked now ,thank you so much my friend !